# Which HTML5 microdata do I use for a job (vacancy)?

Tags: html, microformats, microdata

I'm trying to markup a vacancy/job item with microdata but I wonder whether I'm doing it the right way, because my item properties like 'title' and 'date' don't make sense in combination with my itemtype 'organization'. How could one rewrite the following block better leveraging microdata?

```
        <li itemscope itemtype='http://data-vocabulary.org/Organization'>
            <a href='Web_developer.html'>
                <span itemprop='title'>Web developer</span>
                <span itemprop='name'>Company Name</span>,
                <span itemprop='locality'>City</span>
            </a>
            <p itemprop='summary'>Lorem ipsum dolores amet ...</p>
            <p>Published at <span itemprop='date'>28 Jan 2011</span>,
            <span itemprop='views'>75</span> views</p>
        </li>
```

Or can I create/suggest an itemtype='job' myself? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A web developer is not a type of organization, keep the organization `itemtype` to just describe the organisation offering the job.  For the job itself the closest vocabulary on data-vocabulary.org would appear to be [Offer](http://www.data-vocabulary.org/Offer/) but I would say that's a bit of stretch semantically.

There is a [job-listing](http://microformats.org/wiki/job-listing) brainstorming page on the microformats wiki but it hasn't seen much recent activity, you could try posting on the [mailing list](http://microformats.org/mailman/listinfo/microformats-new/) to see if anyone's interested in taking it forward.  If that gets some traction there may be some benefit to using that vocabulary.

However, I don't think you'll see much immediate benefit to marking up with a non-standard vocabulary so I would recommend confining your microdata to those parts that can be marked up (eg. company contact information) rather than trying to add microdata to everything.

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be a good deal of momentum behind the [JobPosting](http://www.schema.org/JobPosting) microformat. It's part of schema.org.

Here's the blog post announcing it.
http://blog.schema.org/2011/11/schemaorg-support-for-job-postings.html

Answer (score 3):

Answered a long time after the fact, but there is now a ["JobPosting" schema](http://schema.org/JobPosting) at [schema.org](http://schema.org) as cited by Eric. With this your code would look like-

```
<li itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/JobPosting'>
    <a href='Web_developer.html'>
       <span itemprop='title'>Web developer</span>
       <span itemprop='hiringOrganization' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/Organization'>
            <span itemprop='name'>Company Name</span>
       </span>,
       <span itemprop='jobLocation'>City</span>
     </a>
     <p itemprop='description'>Lorem ipsum dolores amet ...</p>
     <p>Published at <time itemprop='datePosted' datetime='2011-01-28'>28 Jan 2011<time>,
     <span>75</span> views</p>
</li>
```

I couldn't find a schema containing a Views property.

Answer (score 0):

i usually get schemas from this website https://issemantic.net/rdf-converter

```
<div itemtype="http://schema.org/JobPosting" itemscope>
    <div itemprop="baseSalary" itemtype="http://schema.org/MonetaryAmount" itemscope>
      <div itemprop="value" itemtype="http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue" itemscope>
        <meta itemprop="unitText" content="HOUR" />
        <meta itemprop="value" content="40" />
      </div>
      <meta itemprop="currency" content="USD" />
    </div>
    <meta itemprop="jobLocationType" content="TELECOMMUTE" />
    <meta itemprop="validThrough" content="2017-03-18T00:00" />
    <meta itemprop="description" content="<p>Google aspires to be an organization that reflects the globally diverse audience that our products and technology serve. We believe that in addition to hiring the best talent, a diversity of perspectives, ideas and cultures leads to the creation of better products and services.</p>" />
    <div itemprop="hiringOrganization" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" itemscope>
      <link itemprop="sameAs" href="http://www.google.com/" />
      <link itemprop="logo" href="http://www.example.com/images/logo.png" />
      <meta itemprop="name" content="Google" />
    </div>
    <meta itemprop="datePosted" content="2017-01-18" />
    <meta itemprop="title" content="Software Engineer" />
    <div itemprop="applicantLocationRequirements" itemtype="http://schema.org/Country" itemscope>
      <meta itemprop="name" content="USA" />
    </div>
    <div itemprop="identifier" itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue" itemscope>
      <meta itemprop="value" content="1234567" />
      <meta itemprop="name" content="Google" />
    </div>
    <div itemprop="experienceRequirements" itemtype="http://schema.org/OccupationalExperienceRequirements" itemscope>
      <meta itemprop="monthsOfExperience" content="36" />
    </div>
    <meta itemprop="employmentType" content="FULL_TIME" />
    <div itemprop="educationRequirements" itemtype="http://schema.org/EducationalOccupationalCredential" itemscope>
      <meta itemprop="credentialCategory" content="bachelor degree" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Enjoy !